# error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, github, bitbucket

When I'm pushing or cloning my project to/form `bit-bucket` it shows me

```
error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have used these but no result found :

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000  

git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
```

I did not solve my problem yet. Please suggest me.

Comment: have you tried via git+ssh?

Comment: No , Please suggest me how to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried cloning it via SSH?

Lets assume you've tried to clone with the command:
`git clone https://USER@bitbucket.org/TEAM/PROJECT.git`

Now to clone that repo via `ssh`, the command should look something like this:
`git clone git@bitbucket.org:TEAM/PROJECT.git`

However for this to work, you need to upload your **public** ssh key into bitbucket.

On your machine you can find out your **ssh public key** with the command:
`cat ~/.ssh/*.pub`

You need to add this key on the **bitbucket site** (change the USER part of the URL to your username):

https://bitbucket.org/account/user/USER/ssh-keys/